# Cannot require a class in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, es6-class

I have two files:

**mysqlDAOFactory.js:**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mysqlUserDAO = require('./mysqlUserDAO');
var mysqlSessionDAO = require('./mysqlSessionDAO');


class mysqlDAOFactory {

    static createConnection() {
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host:'localhost',
            user:'root',
            password:'',
            database:'QASys'
        });
        return connection;
    }

    static getDbInstance() {
        return mysql;
    }

    getUserDAO() {
        return new mysqlUserDAO();
    }
    getSessionDAO() {
        return new mysqlSessionDAO();
    }
}

module.exports = mysqlDAOFactory;
```

**mysqlUserDAO.js:**

```
var mysqlDAOFactory = require('./mysqlDAOFactory.js');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var preparedStatements = require('./preparedStatements');

class mysqlUserDAO {
    constructor() {
        this.connection = mysqlDAOFactory.createConnection();
        this.mysql = mysqlDAOFactory.getDbInstance();
    }
}

module.exports = mysqlUserDAO;
```

When I run the file **test.js:**

```
var mysqlDAOFactory = require('./mysqlDAOFactory.js');
var UserDAO = mysqlDAOFactory.getUserDAO();
```

the program is not recognize the variable mysqlDAOFactory in the constructor of class in **mysqlUserDAO.js** although I require this variable before. 
Can anyone explain to me why this happened?

[results in chrome debugger tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA7bH.jpg)

Comment: I feel the path is not correct. Can you check that once?

Comment: The path is correct, because I've already assigned the variable (var mysqlDAOFactory = require('./mysqlDAOFactory.js') ) inside the constructor and it works. But I want to know why it doesn't work when I put it outside.

Comment: @SnapeSeverus https://repl.it/@DipakC/BeautifulNeglectedProperty

Comment: @SnapeSeverus please review code and let me know whether it wil work to you or not?

Comment: @SnapeSeverus Please review my answer It's nice to help you and let me know if it will resolve your issue or not, if not then still help you to find a solution?

Comment: @Dipakchavda Thank you for your help! Your answer is really helpful. I know the problem arises due to my circular dependencies of require module. I will try to find the solution for that :)

Comment: @snapeSeverus can you tell me what is your idea or what do you want to achieve? Probably I can help you

Comment: I'm not sure about what I should do. I'm trying to figure out how to import and export in the right way! In Java, i just need to import or export the classes I use. But in nodejs, there is a circular dependencies of module so I quite confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed your cod and you made a mistake of circular dependencies due to that you fail to run a code.

I have temporary comment mysqlSession file because you did not post MySQL session file.

Please see the running example then please review link as well.
https://repl.it/@DipakC/SO-50542396cannot-require-a-class-in-nodejs

> test.js:

```
//var mysqlDAOFactory = require('./mysqlDAOFactory');
const mysqlUserDAO = require("./mysqlUserDAO");
let objMysqlUserDAO = new mysqlUserDAO();
console.log("---- ---- ----");
console.log(objMysqlUserDAO);
console.log("---- ---- ----");
```

> mysqlUserDAO.js

```
var mysqlDAOFactory = require('./mysqlDAOFactory');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');    
class mysqlUserDAO {
    constructor() {
        this.connection = mysqlDAOFactory.createConnection();
        this.mysql = mysqlDAOFactory.getDbInstance();
    }
}   
module.exports = mysqlUserDAO;
```

> mysqlDAOFactory.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mysqlUserDAO = require('./mysqlUserDAO');
//var mysqlSessionDAO = require('./mysqlSessionDAO');
class mysqlDAOFactory {
    static createConnection() {
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host:'localhost',
            user:'root',
            password:'',
            database:'QASys'
        });
        return connection;
    }

    static getDbInstance() {
        return mysql;
    }

    static getUserDAO() {
        return new mysqlUserDAO();
    }
    /* getSessionDAO() {
        return new mysqlSessionDAO();
    } */
}
module.exports = mysqlDAOFactory;
```